# How to define id with json to get data

Tags: arrays, json, codeigniter

```
public function getDataPeserta()
    {
      $data['page']='laporan';
      $id_course = 81;
      $table = $this->tinjauan->course_student($id_course); 
        if (count($table) > 0) 
        {
          $no=0;
          foreach ($table as $row) 
            {
                $no++;
                $tab = array();
                $tab["no"] = $no;
                $tab["nip"] = $row['nip'];
                $tab["nama_lengkap"] = $row['nama_lengkap'];
                $tab["email"] = $row['email'];
                $tab["tgl_enroll"] = $row['tgl_enroll'];
                $r_tab[] = $tab;                 
            }
            echo json_encode(array("data" => $r_tab)); 
        }
    }
```

when I define id_course = 81, can display data. But, when I define id_course with $id_course = $this->uri->segment(3); can't display data. How can I define ID with json?

Comment: Have you check whats value is in the $this->uri->segment(3);